# Program with largest array function

Tags: c++, arrays, function

When I try using my function for largest it keeps returning the wrong value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int largest(int[], int);

main()
{
const int size = 3;
int a[size];

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
 {  cout << "Enter an array element ";
     cin >> a[i];   
}


 int large = largest(a,size);
 cout << "Largest is " << largest;

return 0;   
}

int largest (int a[], int size )
{
    int largest;  largest = a[0];


    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] > largest)
        {
        largest = a[i];
        return largest; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Move `return largest;` to the end of the function (after the loop).

Comment: This isn't the problem, but as a matter of style, `int largest;  largest = a[0];` should be `int largest = a[0];`. It's silly to create an uninitialized value and immediately assign a value to it.

Comment: The problem is  here: `cout << "Largest is " << largest;`. You print the address of the function, not the largest number, that would have been ` cout << "Largest is " << large;`

Answer (score 0):

Return statement should be after the for loop in order to find **largest** value.

```
int largest (int a[], int size )
{
    int largest;  largest = a[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] > largest)
            largest = a[i];
    }
    return largest;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems: a) You return the first time something is > a[0], b) you capture the return value in `large` but you print `largest`, which will print the address of the function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int largest(int[], int);

main()
{
const int size = 3;
int a[size];

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
 {  cout << "Enter an array element ";
     cin >> a[i];   
}


 int large = largest(a,size);
 cout << "Largest is " << large;  // print LARGE not LARGEST

return 0;   
}

int largest (int a[], int size )
{
    int largest;  largest = a[0];


    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] > largest)
            largest = a[i];
    }
    return largest;  // return AFTER the loop
}
```